# Applying Condition in Pandas DataFram on more than one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

Kindly help me with the following code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2)
NumberOfStudents=10

MNum=np.random.randint(40,95,NumberOfStudents)
SNum=np.random.randint(40,95,NumberOfStudents)
ENum=np.random.randint(40,95,NumberOfStudents)

df=pd.DataFrame({"Math":MNum,"Science":SNum,"English":ENum}, index=["R"+str(i+1) for i in range(10)])


df["Total"]=df["Math"]+df["Science"]+df["English"]
df["percent"]=df["Total"]/4

df.loc[(df['English'] < 50) or(df['Math'] < 50) or (df['Science'] < 50)  , 'Result'] = 'Fail'

df.loc[(df['English'] >= 50) and (df['Math'] >= 50) and (df['Science'] >= 50)  , 'Result'] = 'Pass'
```

The Last 2 lines cause error it doesn't allow me to apply condition on various column. however condition on one column works fine.

```
df.loc[df['English'] < 50  , 'Result'] = 'Fail'
```

Kindly help me improve this syntax

Comment: change `and` to `&`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with change `and` for bitwise `AND` - `&`:

```
m = (df['English'] < 50) &(df['Math'] < 50) &(df['Science'] < 50)
df['Result'] = np.where(m, 'Fail','Pass')
```

Your solution should be changed with `~` for invert mask:

```
m = (df['English'] < 50) &(df['Math'] < 50) &(df['Science'] < 50)

df.loc[m, 'Result'] = 'Fail'
df.loc[~m, 'Result'] = 'Pass'
```